# Android min SDK versions in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am pretty new to Android development. I just installed eclipse IDE on my mac system to get started with Android development. When I open eclipse right click on package explorer > NEW project > Android > Android Application Project > Assign the application & project name > **Changed the Minimum Required SDK to 11** But still when I click next and choose activity with `navigation type: Tab + Swipe` I am getting the following error.

`This feature requires a minimum SDK version of at least 11, and the current min version is 8`

Though I changed the minimum required SDK to 11 while creating the project but still this issue persists.

I tried changing `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />` in all AndroidManifest.XML files but still I am unable to use many features due to this issue.

Can anyone help me out in fixing this issue?

Comment: check the file *project.properties* too. There is a target change it to 11.

Comment: @t0s - Where can I find this file?

Comment: It's the last file on your Project in Eclipse. Below the Manifest.xml file.

Comment: Thanks, by changing the version in Manifest.XML is side menu helped me. Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your project and then clean it: project > clean.

Comment: @Kerry i wonder why it is marked as correct answer if "this didn't work"

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project, from Android Tools, select clear LINT Markers.

Worked for Me.

Answer (score 1):

Close your eclipse project from workspace and open the project again by double clicking it. This will force Eclipse to reinitialize your project and will also run Lint & Other checks.

Looks like Eclipse does this when you refactor your code that affects entries in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, could not create a new activity through the wizard.
Closing the app-project and re-open helped.